# Is there a way to validate @Value in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-properties

I'm using `@Value` to inject parameters from my properties file to variable in my application. 
Because I'm not the only user in the application and I want to make the injection safety I need to validate the parameter before the injection. 
**Example:**

properties file:

```
example.string=str1,str2
```

app.java

```
@Value(${example.string})
public String example;
```

the expected behavior in this case for example is to throw an exception because I assume "," id delimiter in array case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can directly with `@Value`. But you could do something like this, which will fail on startup if validation fails:

```java
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.prefix")
public class AppProperties {

  //Validation annotations here
  //@NotEmpty
  //@MyCustomValidation
  private String exampleString;


  // getters / setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this before the injection, try to use the post construct method

you can do some thing like that :

```
@PostConstruct
public void validateValue() {
    if (someProperty.contains(",")) {
        throw new MyException("error");
    }
}
```